# Vertex AI model serving - gRPC access - code pointers / samples

Tags: python, grpc, google-cloud-vertex-ai

We have created an endpoint in Vertex AI. We have got the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-custom-models) route working. However, we also want to figure out the gRPC route since that is closest to the gRPC route we had with self managed TF-Serving.
Can someone provide a code pointer for Vertex AI model serving using gRPC (preferably in Python)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gRPC can be used through Vertex Prediction private endpoint, but it is not yet officially supported. See sample here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/community/vertex_endpoints/optimized_tensorflow_runtime/tabular_optimized_online_prediction.ipynb